# Efficiently retrieving resx values in MVC view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on a set of MVC pages which have a large number of string constants stored in a resx file. I'm going to need to pull values from that file very frequently in response to user behavior. As far as I know, I can do this the following ways:

1. Create a partial view and load them in the partial view.
2. Use an ajax call to a controller method that can fetch them as they're called by the user.
3. Create a separate script file and load them all there, then call them as needed.
4. Load them all into the page when it's called and toggle their visibility at need.

Obviously, some of these methods are going to bury the server in requests. However, I'd rather not have to load sixty-odd strings every time the view is called.

Is there a more efficient way to do this? Am I missing something?

Comment: You don't need to do anything to cache them at the server-side, they are already kept in memory there and not "pulled from the file" when you access one.  I assume you are looking for a solution that allows your resx resources to be used in javascript and wondering what your options are?

Comment: If it sounds that off, then sure. I'm hoping to avoid having to load a bunch of things at once or poke the server a hundred times per user (if possible).

Comment: For what it's worth, I went with option 3 with the addition of a custom T4 template that just spits out all of the entries in my resx into a javascript container on compile.